# javascript can't use xul's oncommand?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I am writing firefox extension and I am just wondering if is it possible to use xul's 'oncommand' in .js file which I include to this xul. It may sounds stupid but I decided to ask to be 100% sure it's impossible (or possible :))

I can use it in this situation (xul file):

```
  <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
   <toolbarbutton id="quizy-toolbar-button"
      class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional"
      label="test"
      tooltiptext="test button"
      oncommand="engine.iconCommand()"
   />
 </toolbarpalette>
```

And in my included .js doesn't work.

```
 document.oncommand = function(e){
   alert('tango down');
 };
```

Comment: Can you explain a little on why you wanted to use it and for what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no `oncommand` property (watch [bug 246720](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=246720)).

But you can listen for the `command` event, which is the right way after all.

Comment: That is: `document.getElementById("quizy-toolbar-button").addEventListener("command", function(e) { ... }, false);`. Also, you may execute the command by `document.getElementById("quizy-toolbar-button").doCommand()`.